# How to install VS Code extensions using code-server?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile, vscode-extensions, code-server

Here's my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM linuxserver/code-server:latest

[..]
```

As you can see, I'm using an image that has `code-server` installed. and it works just fine. When I run it, I can see VS Code via `localhost:8443`.

However, when I try to install VS Code extensions there, I receive errors (such as HTTP 403 errors).

How can I fix it?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-code-server/issues/57

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
RUN /app/code-server/bin/code-server \
    --install-extension EXTENSION_ID_1 \
    --install-extension EXTENSION_ID_2 \
    --install-extension EXTENSION_ID_3 \
    --extensions-dir /config/extensions
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be done sequentially in bash, e.g. using a loop or equivalents.

A simple loop example:

```bash
RUN EXT_LIST="ms-toolsai.jupyter ms-python.python" && \
    for EXT in $EXT_LIST; do code-server --install-extension $EXT; done
```

---

The need for such looping is due to a recent change in `code-server`, which no longer accepts multiple arguments passed to a single `--install-extension` argument (which used to accept space-delimited lists at least until v4.9.1).

Be cautious with `xargs` though, as it seems to process only the 1st array element when executed as part of a `RUN` command in a `Dockerfile`.